# Не видны свойства и методы класса

Tags: c#, visual-studio

**Простая формулировка вопроса:**

Есть класс, но его свойства и методы не видны, не смотря на то, что с *namespace*-ами и *public/private/protected/internal* (accessibility levels) все в порядке.

---

**Детальная формулировка вопроса:**

Мой класс разбит на 3 partial-составляющии (распределяется на 3 файла). 
В какой-то момент в одном partial-классе перестали быть видны поля и методы другого. Ошибка: *"Does not exist in current context"*.

- namespace у всех один и тот же
- название у всех одно и то же
- все public
- это не вложенные классы, другие классы в файлах не определяются
- rebuild делал
- этот класс это ViewModel (использую WPF), так что разбивать его на более мелкие классы не удобно, так же, поскольку он получается достаточно большим, то объединять в один файл - не красиво

---

**срез кода:**

```
namespace MyAdmin // файл MyViewModel-List.cs
{
    public partial class MyViewModel
    {
        public MyViewModel()
        {   
            InitializeCommands();
        } 
    }
}

namespace MyAdmin  //файл MyViewModel-Commands.cs
{
    public partial class MyViewModel 
    {
        public void InitializeCommands()
        {
            InitFilterCommands();
        }
    }
}

namespace MyAdmin //файл  MyViewModel-Filter.cs
{
    public partial class MyViewModel 
    {
        private void InitFilterCommands()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hey, dude! Wazzzup?");
        }
    }
}
```

В данном срезе метод InitFilterCommands() не виден из MyViewModel-Commands.cs; Так же в фале MyViewModel-Filter.cs ошибки не выводятся при любой чуши, например:

```
private void InitFilterCommands()
{
    dfbdfhbdfhdfhdddrt;
    MessageBox.Show("Hey, dude! Wazzzup?");
}
```

---

Comment: Код в студию! Желательно, минимальный воспроизводящий пример. Может, у вас опечатка в namespace'е или имени класса?

Comment: @AndreyKomissarov правой кнопкой по файлу, Properties, Build Action - должно быть Compile. Если ошибки компиляции нет - то там не Compile.

Comment: @PashaPash Спасибо огромное! Там действительно стояло не Compile, а EmbeddedResource.  Всего наилучшего!

Comment: @PashaPash: Наверное, стоит опубликовать как ответ? Прекрасный пример филигранного использования миелофона, кстати.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по отсутствию ошибки компиляции в MyViewModel-Filter.cs, этот файл добавлен в проект не как компилируемый исходный код, а как что-то еще.

Правой кнопкой по файлу в Solution Explorer, Properties, Build Action - должно быть выбрано "Compile".